# Uso de callback para trabalhar com javascript assíncrono

Tags: javascript, ajax

Seguindo o código abaixo, existe outra forma melhor de se chamar o método enviaEmail() após ter recebido "success" no ajax chamado pelo método gravaVisita()? Reparem que utilizei callback como solução para este problema.

São 2 arquivos "js":

1. O primeiro arquivo possui o método gravaVisita() que é chamado pela view:

   ```
   this.gravaVisita = function (visitado, visitante) {    
         if (visitado == visitante)
             return;

         dataBD.gravaVisita(visitado, visitante,
             function (data) {
                 if (data.statusRetorno == 200)
                     dataBD.enviaEmail();
             }
         );
   }
   ```
2. Já o segundo é responsável por fazer uma chamada ajax para a action "GravaVisita" do controller "AccountMVVM"

   ```
   function DataBD() {
       this.gravaVisita = function (visitado, visitante, callback) {
           var dataJson = {
               LoginFoiVisitado: visitado,
               LoginVisitou: visitante
           };

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",
               url: "/site/apiPostForm/AccountMVVM/GravaVisita",
               data: dataJson,
               success: function (data) {
                   if (callback) callback(data);
               },
               error: function (error) { }
           });
        }
   }
   var dataBD = new DataBD();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o código já esteja muito bom. Gostei da assincronia!

Uma modificação no sentido de potencializá-la (a assincronia), com vantagens e desvantagens que eu discutirei já já, seria mover a verificação de status (`data.statusRetorno == 200`) para o `success`, dessa forma, mostrando só a parte que interessa:

```
...
success: function (data) {
    if (callback && data.statusRetorno == 200) callback();
}
...
```

Claro, a função callback também sofreria modificações:

```
...
dataBD.gravaVisita(visitado, visitante,
    function () { dataBD.enviaEmail(); }
);
...
```

A vantagem mais óbvia é o código mais enxuto, uma vez que o parâmetro `data` se torna dispensável para a `callback`, que por sua vez só é chamada quando realmente necessária - no caso de sucesso absoluto (200). Dessa maneira, a dependência entre as duas funções (a de `success` e a de `callback`) é mínima.

A desvantagem, e acredito que na verdade você tenha programado da sua maneira justamente por causa dela, é justamente essa dependência mínima; se o seu código de `callback` não pára por aí, as próximas linhas não terão acesso ao objeto `data` e suas valiosas (suponho eu!) informações.

Logo: se as modificações melhoram ou pioram seu programa, está por sua conta decidir. Só espero que tenha te ajudado a raciocinar :D